# The method body() in the type ResponseOptions<Response> is not applicable for the arguments

Tags: rest-assured

Exception:

> - The method body() in the type ResponseOptions is not applicable for the arguments (String,equalTo("ShipVia"))
> - The method equalsTo(String) is undefined for the type String

code:

```
Response Query1= RestAssured.
            given().body("{\"SearchedString\":\"orderdate , customerid by 
            shipvia \",\"IsTobeSearch\":true,\"dict\":\"{}\"}\r\n" + "").
            header("access_token", token).
            when().
            post("http://xyz/ProcessNLQ").
            then().assertThat().statusCode(200).
            and().contentType(ContentType.JSON).and().
            extract().response().
body("data.reportDefinition.reportPart[0].
reportPartContent.columns.elements[0].name",equalTo("ShipVia"));

    //print body in pretty raw format
        String Q1 =Query1.prettyPrint();
```

It is throwing me error as :

> - The method body() in the type ResponseOptions is not applicable for the arguments (String,equalTo("ShipVia"))

Comment: Welcome to stackoverflow. Please edit your quesiton and properly format it using code tags. Currently the code is unreadable.

Comment: @M.Deinum - hopefully the code is now readable?